# What is needed for $y=f(x)$ to be considered a function?

Tags: functions

When is an equation of the form $ y = f(x)$ not a function? Does it need to be surjective, injective, both, neither? I vaguely remember something called the vertical line test, but it's not making any connections in my brain.

Also, I'm reading a book about differential equations and there's a sentence in it that brought this question to mind. It reads, "the equation $ y = \sqrt{-(1+x^2)}$ does not define a function." What is it about that equation/corresponding graph that fails the definition of a function?

Comment: This seems to be well addressed by [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Total,_univalent_relation). Is there a point there that is unclear?

Comment: Just to add: your book probably means that $x \mapsto \sqrt{-1 - x^2}$ doesn't define a real-valued function. Notice that $-1 - x^2$ is always negative and so it doesn't have a real square root.

Comment: If one was feeling a bit mischievous, they could argue that your last equation does define a function, but one whose domain is the empty set. But that's a rather pathological example of a function.

Comment: consult any precalculus textbook, they elaborate a bit more on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $y=f(x)$ to be called a 'function' it has to meet a certain criteria,

(i) There should be a value of $y$ for every value of $x$

(ii) There should be **only one** value of $y$ for every value of $x$(**This is why we do vertical line test**)

(iii) For every value of $x$, $y$ should be defined.

**Vertical line test:-** If any vertical line cuts the graph of the given function at more than one point, then it's not a function. It means for a single value of $x$, if you see the graph giving more than one value of $y$ then it's not a function (as stated above)

**1.** Let's take $y=x(x-1)(x-2)$

[image]

Notice that any vertical line does not cut the curve at more than one point, also notice that for every value of $x$ in its domain($x\in R$), $y$ is defined(the curve is continuous everywhere in its domain).

So $y=x(x-1)(x+1)$ is a 'function'

**2.** Now let's say $y^2=1-x^2$

[image]

Notice that any vertical line cuts the curve at more than one point, that means for a single value of $x$, we get more than one value of $y$.

So $y^2=1-x^2$ is **not** a 'function'

Now your question about $y=\sqrt{-(1+x^2)}$

$1+x^2$ is always $\ge 1$ for **any** value of $x$

So, $-(1+x^2)$ is always $\le -1$ for **any** value of $x$

That means the thing inside the square root always remains negative for any value of $x$. So, there is **no** real value of $y$ for any value of $x$. That's why it's not a function.

I hope its clear now.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. That clears things up. You rock.